# Find location of line on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, android-webview

So I have HTML text being rendered in a browser (in this case an Android WebView). I want to find out what the (x,y) location in pixels of any given line of text is **AFTER**  it is rendered. The working definition of line I am using is not just all the text contained in a `<p>` tag or that appears before a `<br>` tag. I mean a line as it would appear to the user.

I am open to any suggested method.

Is there any CSS property that you are able to find the number of lines in a div and their respective heights? That would provide a workable solution.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access a line individually. But, with some JavaScript, you can find the position of a line with a known index; here's a basic outline:

```
var p = document.getElementById("ptag"); //get the text container that contains your line
var nthline = 3; //the line for which you'd like to find the position
var lnheight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p).lineHeight); //get the height of each line
var linepos = [p.offsetLeft, p.offsetTop + lnheight * (nthline - 1)]; //a [left, top] pair that represents the line's position
```

**Note:** This assumes the container doesn't have anything but text.

Comment: What if my element has spans and the like inside of it?

Comment: @Jon Then you can create an element just around the main piece of text.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way of doing that, you will have to refer to your imagination and invent some hack, right now I can think of two ideas for this:

1. Enclose each word within a span, like `<span
   class="word">word</span>`, that could easily be done with regex or
   string functions, later loop over each `<span>` reading its
   position, add some calculation and you could find out how many
   lines, where a line starts (word that incremented its `top` position
   from last one) and when a line ends (last word of line + width of
   that word).
2. Apply some style to first line using `:first-line` pseudoelement,
   like

   p:first-line{    background-color: white; /* same existent color so
   no affecting display*/  }

   later find in DOM what text that style was applied. This idea is not
   as good and first one but maybe it can make you think of other ways.