# How do I find space between lines in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, android-webview

This is a follow-up question to a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537001/find-location-of-line-on-screen). I am trying to find a way to find the exact location of each line of text in an element.

I was able to find the css `lineHeight` attribute (see previous answer). The problem is that the height of my element is slightly larger than the cumulative height of the number of lines times the `lineHeight`.

*An example:*

I have a `<p>` that is 2010px tall without padding, border, or margin, (`scrollHeight`, `offsetHeight`, and `clientHeight` all report the same,) and has 89 lines in the browser. The `lineHeight` of the `computedStyle()` is 22.

2010 / 22 = 91.37 lines

With small elements I can just floor the value to get the correct number of lines, but run into the above problem with larger elements where I cannot accurately get the exact number of lines.

**My assumption is that there is some small space between these lines of text I am not taking into account. Any idea how to find it?** Does it have to do with font types? Is it automatically set by the browser? Any documentation would be especially helpful.

Thanks!!

***Update:***

So I have 26 superscripts in my `<p>`, each of which protrude up 2px, extending the `lineHeight` of those lines on which they appear to 24px, which accounts for my missing space. (Woot! Thanks so far!)

**I guess the boat I am in now is that I need to find a way to dynamically calculate how much they protrude above the normal top of the line, or discover how much higher the baseline of a `<sup>` is above the normal baseline. (Vice-versa for a `<sub>`.)
Otherwise, could I determine that with CSS?**

Comment: Might want to read this http://blog.typekit.com/2010/07/14/font-metrics-and-vertical-space-in-css/

Comment: @j08691 Thank you. That was a helpful article about how vertical spaces can dip up & down. It was vague though, and did not say how to find those spaces, or if they are included in the `lineHeight` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superscripts and subscripts usually protrude above and below the line boundaries, as illustrated in [this demo](http://jsbin.com/ogoruy/1/edit) — you see that the left example has more apparent space between the lines than the right one, even though they have the same `line-height`. Unfortunately, browser "typography" (if you can call it that) does not allow you to determine *how much* the sub/super-scripts protrude, so you cannot take that into account when you calculate the actual line heights.

Comment: That makes a heap-ton of sense. I am sure I could find the height of the sub/superscript span, but there is no standard for how high sub/superscripts dip above & below the line? ex: "Superscripts have their top half above the top line of text, and bottom half below."

Comment: No, [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-sub-and-sup-elements.html#the-sub-and-sup-elements) does not define such rendering details.

Comment: Here's the actual CSS markup spec which browsers use for `<sup>`. Note the lack of specification on the % to apply for 'super' / 'sub'.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align

Answer (score 2):

Providing my own answer, as @lanzz's is incomplete to some extent.

If you define the block element as:

```
div {
 font-size: 10px;
 line-height: 10px;
 height:30px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 border: 0px;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 padding: 0px;
}
```

you will get sufficient space for EXACTLY 3 lines. However, if you have sub-scripts or super-scripts less lines are visible. By removing the overflow you can force it to only display 3 lines of space.

This is demonstrable at: http://jsbin.com/ogoruy/4/

Superscript and Subscript are 'inline-block elements':

> The height of the inline box encloses all glyphs and their half-leading on each side and is thus exactly 'line-height'.
>
> When there is only one value of 'line-height' for all inline boxes in a block container box and they are all in the same font (and there are no replaced elements, inline-block elements, etc.), the above will ensure that baselines of successive lines are exactly 'line-height' apart.
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height

Comment: Those are some extremely helpful articles. It has given me MUCH more information than before! Unfortunately I am unable to implement your solution for my exact situation. Though, it is a wonderful solution.